# Get min value of a relation using "with()"

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship, laravel-10, laravel-relations

I'm trying to get all my users that has a `HasMany` relation. I want to get the min value of column in relation and retrieve it with the user.

I'm trying this code, it works but it gives me all the model relation, not the one I'm looking for.

`first()` didn't work as well.

Any suggestion?

```
$users = User::with(['posts' => function($query) {$query->min('created_at');}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `setRelation` method here to change how we are pulling back to the related post. Using the `oldest` method means we get the oldest post by the `created_at` field. This can be reversed using the `latest` method.

```php
User::with('posts')->get()->map(function($user) {
    $user->setRelation('posts', $user->posts->oldest());
    return $user;
});
```